# Error de Acceso denegado en Xamarin

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, pdf, xamarin

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.Android y me da el siguiente error cuando intento crear un PDF en el dispositivo...

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/mnt/sdcard-ext" is denied.

Lo raro es que en el manifiesto de android tengo tildado los permisos de lectura y escritura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Este es el código que uso para crear el PDF

```
//Uso el directorio "/mnt/sdcard-ext" que es la ruta original de la memoria externa, de lo contrario crea un directorio emulado y no puedo ver el pdf en el dispositivo si lo busco manualmente
var directory = new Java.IO.File("/mnt/sdcard-ext", "pdf").ToString();
if (!Directory.Exists(directory)){
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory); //Aquí me da el error
}

var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "PdfTest.pdf");

if (File.Exists(path)){
    File.Delete(path);
}

var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
document.Open();
document.Add(new Paragraph("Hola mundo!"));
document.Close();
writer.Close();
fs.Close();

Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), "application/pdf");
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Probaste con Permisos en tiempo de ejecución, según la versión de android en la que ejecutas la App?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=vswin. Acá podes ver un articulo que puede ayudarte, a partir de Android 6.0 tenes que pedir los permisos en tiempo de ejecución y podes usar el Tarjet Android Versión en lo mas alto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final el problema estaba en el Manifiesto de Android.

En el "Target Android Version" tuve que poner la version Android 5.1 (Anteriormente tenía la 6.0) y con eso se solucionó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]